# HAProxy cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:8888]

Tags: sockets, haproxy, centos7

I build a HAProxy on CentOS 7 and enable statistics page with port 8080. It seems work properly. 
When I set port as 8888, the HAProxy is not working and gives me some feedback.
After that, I tried many ways to solve this problem, but the problem is still there.

Does anyone can help me deal with this issue?

### Here is the system information

**haprxoy.cfg**

> /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
>   Port 8080 is fine, 8888 is not working.

```
    # [HAPROXY DASHBOARD]
        listen  stats :8888
        mode http
        stats enable
        stats hide-version
        stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
        stats uri /
        stats auth haproxy:haproxy
        stats refresh 10s
```

**Service Status**

> service haproxy status

```
systemd[1]: Started HAProxy Load Balancer.
haproxy-systemd-wrapper[2358]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: executing /usr/sbin/haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cf...id -Ds
haproxy-systemd-wrapper[2358]: [ALERT] 012/095413 (2359) : Starting proxy stats: cannot bind socket [0.0.0.0:8888]
haproxy-systemd-wrapper[2358]: haproxy-systemd-wrapper: exit, haproxy RC=256
```

**/etc/sysctl.conf**
Someone said that could be a **Virtual IP** problem, so I follow the instruction and add the setting below then run sysctl -p

```
net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
```

**Network Confgiuration**

> ip addr show

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:0a:09:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.4.117/24 brd 192.168.4.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe0a:905/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Listening Ports**

> ss --listening

```
[root@localhost ~]# ss --listening
Netid State      Recv-Q Send-Q                                                                                  Local Address:Port                                                                                      Peer Address:Port
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                rtnl:NetworkManager/792                                                                                               *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                rtnl:kernel                                                                                                *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                rtnl:avahi-daemon/671                                                                                               *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                rtnl:4195096                                                                                               *
nl    UNCONN     4352   0                                                                                             tcpdiag:ss/3772                                                                                               *
nl    UNCONN     768    0                                                                                             tcpdiag:kernel                                                                                                *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   6:kernel                                                                                                *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   7:kernel                                                                                                *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   7:systemd/1                                                                                               *      
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   7:dbus-daemon/680                                                                                               *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   9:auditd/640                                                                                               *     
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   9:kernel                                                                                                *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   9:systemd/1                                                                                               *      
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  10:kernel                                                                                                *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  11:kernel                                                                                                *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:iprdump/723                                                                                               *    
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:systemd/1                                                                                               *      
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:-4124                                                                                                 *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:systemd-logind/679                                                                                               *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:NetworkManager/792                                                                                               *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:iprinit/713                                                                                               *    
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:-4107                                                                                                 *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:-4125                                                                                                 *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:-4119                                                                                                 *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:iprupdate/710                                                                                               *  
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:-4118                                                                                                 *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:kernel                                                                                                *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:-4117                                                                                                 *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  15:tuned/676                                                                                               *      
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  16:kernel                                                                                                *
nl    UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  18:kernel                                                                                                *
u_str LISTEN     0      128                                                                           /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket 11542                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      128                                                                       /run/systemd/journal/stdout 6697                                                                                                 * 0
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                         /run/systemd/journal/socket 6700                                                                                                 * 0
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                            /dev/log 6702                                                                                                 * 0
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                              /run/systemd/shutdownd 11321                                                                                                * 0
u_dgr LISTEN     0      128                                                                                 /run/udev/control 11338                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                      public/flush 18726                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                      public/showq 18741                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      30                                                               /var/run/NetworkManager/private-dhcp 17003                                                                                                * 0
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                   @/org/freedesktop/systemd1/notify 11259                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                    private/tlsmgr 18708                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      30                                                                    /var/run/NetworkManager/private 16518                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      128                                                                      /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket 13986                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      128                                                                   /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 13998                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                   private/rewrite 18711                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                    private/bounce 18714                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                     private/defer 18717                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                     private/trace 18720                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                    private/verify 18723                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                  private/proxymap 18729                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                private/proxywrite 18732                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                      private/smtp 18735                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                     private/relay 18738                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                     private/error 18744                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                     private/retry 18747                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                   private/discard 18750                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                     private/local 18753                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                   private/virtual 18756                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                      private/lmtp 18759                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                     private/anvil 18762                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                    private/scache 18765                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                     public/pickup 18697                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                    public/cleanup 18701                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      100                                                                                       public/qmgr 18704                                                                                                * 0
u_str LISTEN     0      30                                                                               /run/systemd/private 11261                                                                                                * 0
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 14733                                                                                                * 6700
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 15011                                                                                                * 6702
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 12659                                                                                                * 12658
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 18818                                                                                                * 6702
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 15244                                                                                                * 6702
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 16991                                                                                                * 6702
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 12644                                                                                                * 6700
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 12658                                                                                                * 12659
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 19513                                                                                                * 6700
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 29994                                                                                                * 6702
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 13899                                                                                                * 6702
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 16528                                                                                                * 6702
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 30457                                                                                                * 6702
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 18632                                                                                                * 6702
u_dgr UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   * 16504                                                                                                * 6702
raw   UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                  :::ipv6-icmp                                                                                             :::*     
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   *:ipproto-5353                                                                                              *:*  
tcp   UNCONN     0      0                                                                                                   *:ipproto-50900                                                                                              *:* 
tcp   LISTEN     0      100                                                                                         127.0.0.1:smtp                                                                                                 *:*
tcp   LISTEN     0      128                                                                                                 *:ssh                                                                                                  *:*
tcp   LISTEN     0      100                                                                                               ::1:smtp                                                                                                :::*
tcp   LISTEN     0      128                                                                                                :::ssh                                                                                                 :::*
```

Comment: have you checked if port is in use already? `netstat -anp | grep ":8888"`

Comment: I have already checked. Not in use.

Comment: Check rule selinux, see /var/log/audit/audit.log

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Thanks for you guys at first.
I have solved this issue by following command.
`setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any=1`

It works for me!

Comment: If stack-overflow had a donate-a-dollar button, you would definitely be getting a dollar =).  That would be an awesome feature actually - people would use the platform more and earn money!

Comment: I wish I could give this comment a dollar.

Comment: For reference: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-haproxy_selinux/

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work on FreeBSD and OpnSense (no such command). :(

Comment: I guess a better approach would be [Creating Custom SELinux Policy Modules with audit2allow](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#Creating_Custom_SELinux_Policy_Modules_with_audit2allow)

Comment: This does this : 
If you want to allow users to resolve user passwd entries directly from ldap rather then using a sssd server, you must turn on the authlogin_nsswitch_use_ldap boolean. Disabled by default.

Comment: will this setting persist after reboot

Answer (score 15):

Add net.ipv4.ip_nonlocal_bind=1 on /etc/sysctl.conf

sysctl -p

Restart the haproxy service(service restart haproxy). it will work.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess this is a SELinux issue. 
Try setenforce 0, then restart the HAProxy service. If HAProxy works after this change, restore the enforcing status with setenforce 1, and then run setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any to change the SELinux boolean that is probably affecting this, and restart the service again.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is killing any service that was running on the port I wanted to use (6443):

```
$fuser -k 6443/tcp
```

Then I ran:

```
$sudo systemctl restart haproxy
```

Answer (score 1):

setsebool shows the right direction.
It is a SELinux issue. Try to install the toolchain for SELinux:
yum install policycoreutils policycoreutils-python selinux-policy selinux-policy-targeted libselinux-utils setroubleshoot-server setools setools-console mcstrans

Press the "Record-Button" by typing "`selinux permissive`" and try to start the
services. They fail.
Then: `grep haprox /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M haproxy`
and activate the haproxy permissions by

```
semodule -i haproxy.pp
```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

You don't always need to **dosetsebool -P haproxy_connect_any=1**

For me issue was the port that I was unable to bind was actually running actively.

So in my case ( on ubuntu ) I use `fuser tcp/8888` it was saying it is up on some XXXX port. So get rid of that `fuser -k tcp/8888`.  In my case it started properly.

Answer (score 1):

In continuation of [Code Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1357803/code-man) answer

> `setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any=1`

I'm running RHEL, and the way to set a SELinux boolean has the following syntax:

`setsebool -P haproxy_connect_any on`

Answer (score 0):

Code Man's answer works, but also you may manage selinux for your port with:

```
yum -y install policycoreutils-python
semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 8080
systemctl restart haproxy
systemctl status haproxy
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar message of `Starting frontend <FrontendName>: cannot bind socket <IP:port>` on an OpnSense firewall (FreeBSD).

I was binding to a domain name and it turns out that it was pointing to my public address and that was a problem. Using a loopback address made HAProxy work.

This Linux-related answer gives some hints as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41009557/964053
...because I remember this working on pfSense. There is probably more magic to be discovered here!

Answer (score -1):

/etc/sysconfig/selinux
SELINUX=permissive

reboot

worked for me